# Fix Size in Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am Integrating google map.When I hover on marker it shows me location on marker.But my problem is when I hover on marker map moves. I want when I hover on marker position should be fixed.Here is My code:

```
 function CreateMarker(Obj){
            var $j=jQuery.noConflict();
            var pos;
            var allMarkers = [];
            pos = new google.maps.LatLng(Obj['latitude'], Obj['longitude']);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map,
                zoom:14,
                icon: gicons["blue"]
            });
            latlngbounds.extend(pos);
            var str = '<div class="google_popup"><span style="color:#00aeef; font-weight:bold; font-size: 14px;  ">'+Obj['name']+'</span></b><div>'+Obj['address']+'</div><div>'+Obj['city']+', '+Obj['state']+' '+Obj['zip']+'</div><div> <a href="mailto:'+Obj['email']+'" title="'+Obj['email']+'">'+Obj['email']+'</a></div><div>'+Obj['phone']+'</div></div>';
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                map.panTo(pos);
                map.setZoom(14);
                info.setContent(str);
                info.open(map, marker);
                //openTrInfo($("#" + Obj['elemID'])[0], false);
                var emid=Obj['elemID'];
                merchant_deals(emid);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function () {
                marker.setIcon(gicons["grey"]);
            //    map.panTo(pos);
                info.setContent(str);
                info.open(map, marker);
                var emid=Obj['elemID'];

            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function () {
                marker.setIcon(gicons["blue"]);
                info.close(map, marker);
            });
            gmarkers.push(marker);
            return marker;
        }
```

Comment: All you have to do, is remove lines 15 an 16.  As you can read, map.panTo(pos);  map.setZoom(14); pans and zooms to the location of the marker

Answer (score 0):

When you create your infowindow, set the `disableAutoPan` property to false.  By default this is true, so the map automatically pans when the infowindow opens, when you do `info.open(map, marker);`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions

Answer (score 0):

```
var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({

                        disableAutoPan: true
                });
```